# Less CSS - Additional rules for class when used on a specific element type

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to define additional rules for a class when it is used on a specific element type?

For example: I want to add a `.center` class that aligns text to center.

```
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Now, if that class is used on an `img` element, I want additional rules:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Is there a LESS way to do this? I've tried using mixins to bundle it but it's kind of the opposite nesting of how they're supposed to work. This is what I've tried:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;

    &img {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean if it's used on `div` than use `text-align: center;` if on `img` than use `display: block; ...` and drop `text-align`?

Comment: Yeah I guess. No need to drop the `text-align` rule though. More focused on just getting the `img` rules in the LESS way, if there even is one.

Comment: So your less rules will generate `img.center { text-align:center; display: block; ...}`

Comment: @Justinas Was it you that posted the `img&` answer? That was correct. What I have now doesn't do that

Comment: @AndréDion: Pinging just in case you want to undelete that answer mate. It seems perfectly fine to me (although I guess there are some previous duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my `&` selector being in the wrong position. I also added a `:not` selector to remove the `text-align: center` property from the `img` rules.

```
.center {
    &:not(img) {
        text-align: center;
    }

    img& {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had just tried to ping the user who had originally answered the question mate.

Comment: @Harry If he posts it again I'll remove this. Figured better to have the answer visible.

Comment: @Mr.E: Absolutely nothing wrong mate. I just wanted to let you know.